# Loading python module with GUI

Tags: python

I have a organization setup question I need help with. Here is my current folder structure.

[image]

What i want to do is run the Main UI with the specified AppCommands module that contains functions. Based on which application i want to run the tool. Is there a way using another python file, where i can load the gui and the associated app commands moduel? So when users click the button it calls the corrects app command.

So say for example I create a python file like this pseudo code

**main execute py file for Photoshop**

```
 Import photoshop.appcommands as cmds
 Import GUI
 Gui(cmds)
```

How do I then tell my main GUI tool to load the photoshop modules 'AppCommands' when it runs?

**app #1 code:**

```
def runTool():
    msg = 'This is Notepad'
    print msg
```

**app #2 code:**

```
def runTool():
    msg = 'This is Photoshop'
    print msg
```

**Main ui code:**

```
import sys
import os
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import AppCommands as cmds

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.uiButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)

        # layout
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.uiButton, 3, 1)
        main_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        self.uiButton.clicked.connect(self.browse_clicked)

    # actions
    def browse_clicked(self):
        print 'Execute Command'
        cmds.runTool()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: change `import AppCommands as cmds` to `import {xxxxx}.AppCommands as cmds`

Comment: that's a great idea, how do i then run the tool with the specified module?

Comment: How are you determining the specified module?

Comment: Which module do you want to run notepad or photoshop?

Comment: I would do it with another python file.. I'm just not sure how to properly do this

Comment: I do not understand what you want, explain yourself better, which module do you want to execute?

Comment: I still do not understand you, as you choose which module you want to execute.

Comment: say i have a python file which runs this code GUI(notepad) how can I then actually load that module when the tool runs?

Comment: @eyllanesc i added more to question explaining my main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood correctly, you need to choose the right module to load a function after then you started the program with some variable args?

In this case you may import both and try globals:

```
import notepad.AppCommands
import photoshop.AppCommands

...

# in your app init code:

x = 'photoshop' # an arg passed from config/CLI or from somewhere else
actual_module = globals()[x]
actual_module.AppComands.runTools()
```

++ But if you just don't know how to run a certain function from a certain module, follow @eyllanesc's answer.